# My Comouter steels networks!

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet

I used to connect to WiFi networks and it was going well, but now every time I try to connect I connect OK, but I kill the network connections on my other machine! How did this happen? I have already tried the following solution.

Can anyone help?

the solution was to open up the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add

```
blacklist bcm43xxblacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist bcma
blacklist ndiswrapper
blacklist wl
```

Next, open up the file `/etc/modules` and add the following at the end of the file:

```
brcmsmac
```

Alternatively, you can type sudo `sh -c "echo 'brcmsmac' >> /etc/modules"` in a terminal to do this all at once.

Finally reboot the machine.

Now, what caused this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Broadcom wireless cards for which there are two drivers. As you might expect, one usually works well and the other not well at all. The 'Additional Drivers' utility happily offers and installs the wrong driver in a few cases, as you've seen.

I suggest you also run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

You should also remove bcma from the `blacklist.conf` file. One of the dependencies of brcmsmac is bcma; you need both.